# Angular 2 HTML template in Visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 dashboard in Visual studio 2015, MVC project. I downloaded a sample dashboard and using it as reference.

*login.component.ts*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.scss']
})
export class Login {

  public form:FormGroup;
  public email:AbstractControl;
  public password:AbstractControl;
  public submitted:boolean = false;

  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
      'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])]
    });

    this.email = this.form.controls['email'];
    this.password = this.form.controls['password'];
  }

  public onSubmit(values:Object):void {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.form.valid) {
      // your code goes here
      // console.log(values);
    }
  }
}
```

In that reference dashboard, they have used login.html template, in which the label values are referenced as **{{'login.title'}}, {{'login.signup_link'}},{{'login.email'}}, {{'login.password'}}** etc.  I don't understand from where there are getting this label values.

*login.html*

```
<div class="auth-main">
  <div class="auth-block">
    <h1 translate>{{'login.title'}}</h1>
    <a routerLink="/register" class="auth-link" translate>{{'login.signup_link'}}</a>

    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!email.valid && email.touched), 'has-success': (email.valid && email.touched)}">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate>{{'login.email'}}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input [formControl]="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="{{'login.email' | translate}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!password.valid && password.touched), 'has-success': (password.valid && password.touched)}">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label" translate>{{'login.password'}}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input [formControl]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="{{'login.password' | translate}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
          <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-auth" translate>{{'login.sign_in'}}</button>
          <a routerLink="/login" class="forgot-pass" translate>{{'login.forgot_password'}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="auth-sep"><span><span translate>{{'login.sign_from_app_text'}}</span></span></div>

    <div class="al-share-auth">
      <ul class="al-share clearfix">
        <li><i class="socicon socicon-facebook" title="{{'login.share_on_facebook' | translate}}"></i></li>
        <li><i class="socicon socicon-twitter" title="{{'login.share_on_twitter' | translate}}"></i></li>
        <li><i class="socicon socicon-google" title="{{'login.share_on_google_plus' | translate}}"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no reference to those variables in the code. Are you sure it's the right file ?

Comment: Yes this is the HTML file they are referencing in login.component.ts file.

Comment: And it's in the same folder ? Or there are several login.html files and you happened to open it with Ctrl+P ?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder and have only one login.html file. Is there any syntax to get values in this form {{' object.value '}} in Angular 2?

Comment: Well it shouldn't work like that. Unless login was injected into the constructor but it doesn't seem to be the case ... What do you mean by that ? You want to get the values of your form group ?

Comment: Yes you are right.. That's my doubt here. No not from the form group, somewhere else like globally declared variables?

Comment: Oh I see, well only if the global variable is declared in your component (for all I know), and it doesn't seem to be the case here. Can you confirm those are the raw files you just copy/pasted, and that they work with this code on another project ?

Comment: Since it is a downloaded document, I think, might be they are insisting us to fill with our own text in those labels, but not sure. Ok i will check. thank you :)

Comment: I think so yes, anyway it won't be long to change it, good luck !

Comment: They are translation keys. The `translate` directive will look at what is in the element, and will try to translate those

Comment: Hi one question.. {{ ' login.forgot_password ' }} --> interpolation we can read object inside string quote ?